# Strange behavior with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

Here is a code from my application:

```
NSMutableArray *firstPhotoVoters = post.firstPhotoVoters;
NSMutableArray *secondPhotoVoters = post.secondPhotoVoters;

ALog(@"First voters: %@", firstPhotoVoters);
ALog(@"Second voters: %@", secondPhotoVoters);

for (Post* _post in posts) {
    if ([_post.objectId isEqualToString:post.objectId]) {
        [_post.firstPhotoVoters removeAllObjects];
        [_post.secondPhotoVoters removeAllObjects];

        ALog(@"Count: %d", firstPhotoVoters.count);

        ALog(@"Updated post: %@", _post);
    }
}
```

The two ALog statements (which is a macro for NSLog) dumps the array elements that exist in firstPhotoVoters and secondPhotoVoters arrays. However, inside the for loop the two arrays appear all empty. firstPhotoVoters.count is always zero. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: You've just emptied the array and then you log it. It should be outside the if-statement.

Comment: This is the stupidest mistake I have ever made. Thank you Mikael.

Comment: it happens to all of us :) Ok if I post it as an answer?

Comment: in either case, this question will be closed, so better to remove yourself @ÉlodiePetit.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya understandable :)

Comment: @Mikael Yes, you can post the answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just emptied the array and then you log it. It should be outside the if-statement.